# Concerning integer types of bits in Dev-C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I'm using Dev-C++ compiler and wxDev-C++ compiler whilst reading the C++ Primer Plus to learn the programming language. My book's literal explanation of integer types is as follows:

> - A short integer is at least 16 bits wide.
> - An int integer is at
>     least as big as short.
> - A long integer is at least 32 bits wide and
>     at least as big as int.
> - A long long integer is at least 64 bits wide
>     and at least as big as long.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Which part needs clarifying?

Comment: I don't quite understand how long is at least 32 bits AND as wide as int, while int is at least as big as short which is 16 bits wide.

Comment: It's simply saying `bits_long >= bits_int` and `bits_long >= 32`.

Comment: The size can change depending upon platform and compiler.  There are tools that allow you to know how "big" a datatype is (for example sizeof).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got to admit after long thinking I still don't understand where you need clarification but still gonna try to help you.

The c++ standard doesn't explicitly tell how many bits `short`, `int`, `long` or `long long` use but rather gives limits and leaves the rest up to the implementation. The limits are like you listed already.

As example:

- On my Windows machine I got `short` = 16 bit, `int` and
  `long` both are 32 bit and `long long` is 64 bit.
- On my Linux machine    I got `short` = 16 bit, `int` = 32 bit, `long`
  and `long long` are    both 64 bit. As you can see implementation of
  `long` is different.

If you want to know how to find out how many bits a certain type uses on your platform/compiler try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT;
    return 0;
}
```

You can replace int with another type if you want.

Also you could look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer for some types with fixed bit width.

I hope that helps you since I don't really know how else I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through the list one by one.

- A `short` integer is at least 16 bits wide.

  This means that there can be platforms where a `short` is 16 bits, platforms where it is 17 bits, platforms where it is 18 bits, etc., but no platform can give you a short that has only 17 bits or less.

  So, for the sake of the argument, let's define several different platforms, which we just name with capital letters. Say platforms A to D have 16 bit `short`, E and F have 32 bit `short`, and platform G has 1024 bit `short`. All of those platforms are conforming so far.
- An `int` integer is at least as big as short.

  This means that you cannot make `int` smaller than `short`, but you can make it arbitrary large. For example, platforms A to D above could all use 16 bit `int`, but platforms E and F would have to make `int` at least 32 bits, and platform F must make it at least 1024 bits.

  Let's assume that A chooses 16 bits, B, C and E choose 32 bits, D and F choose 64 bits, and G chooses again 1024 bits. All those choices fulfil the rules so far.
- A `long` integer is at least 32 bits wide and at least as big as `int`.

  Here we have *two* conditions. First, we have that `long` has to have at least 32 bits. So even platform A cannot choose `long` to be only 16 bits. Second, `long` also cannot be shorter than `int`, which means e.g. platforms D and `F` could not have 32 bit `long` because it would be shorter than their `int`. And for platform G, the minimum size for `long` is again 1024 bits.

  So possible choices would be that platforms A, B and E choose 32 bit long, platforms C, D and F choose 64 bits, and G chooses 1024 bits.
- A `long long` integer is at least 64 bits wide and at least as big as `long`.

  Without going into detail again, now platforms A to F could all choose 64 bit or larger, and G could choose 1024 bits or larger.

  Let's assume for completeness that platforms A to D choose 64 bits, E and F choose 128 bits, and G chooses 1024 bits.

Then we get the following list of platforms which *all* would be valid (but they are by far not all possible valid platforms):

```
           A     B     C     D     E     F     G
short      16    16    16    16    32    32    1024
int        16    32    32    64    32    64    1024
long       32    32    64    64    32    64    1024
long long  64    64    64    64    128   128   1024
```

Platform A would be a typical 16 bit platform (except that at the time 16 bit platforms were current, `long long` wasn't yet an official type). Platform B would be a typical 32 bit platform, but also represents many 64 bit platforms. Platform C also is a possible 64 bit platform implementation. All others I don't believe are used anywhere, but they would be valid implementations anyway.

As you can see, e.g. on some platforms `int` has the same size as `short`, on others it has the same size as `long`, and on yet others, it may be somewhere in between, and on some platforms `short` and `long` may have the same size, in which case `int` also must have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you just don't understand how integers are represented on modern hardware. Go read about how you represent a number in binary first:

[Binary number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number)

Each bit represents a `0` or `1` in the binary representation of a number. To represent negative numbers we use some special tricks, which you can read about here:

[Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) (used for signed numbers, e.g. C's `int` type)

How many "bits wide" the type is just constrains the largest (and smallest negative) numbers the type can represent. For example, the `short` type can represent numbers `-32768` to `32767` with its 16 bits, whereas a 32-bit integer can represent `-2147483648` to `2147483647`.